# OS X Yosemite Submit App Using XCode5 Code Sign Error

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode5, osx-yosemite

I use os x yosemite and XCode 5 and i want to submit my app to appstore but i see an error like this

"the main executable or Info.plist must be a regular file (no symlinks, etc.)"

[image]

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Is your app using a symlink instead of a regular file for your executable or Info.plist?

Comment: My app is not using a symlink instead of a regular file

Answer (score 5):

codesign under the Yosemite beta does not like special characters in file names. This is a known bug. However it should also be noted that you are not allowed to submit to the Apple Store from Yosemite even if you are using Xcode 5 and have the command line tools set to Xcode 's tools. This problem should help you understand why. Even if you are using Xcode 5 and it's tools, it is not completely insulated from the fact it is running on Yosemite.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Even if you did fix the code sign issue, Apple doesn't accept content from pre-release software.

Comment: ```However it should also be noted that you are not allowed to submit to the Apple Store from Yosemite even if you are using Xcode 5 and have the command line tools set to Xcode 's tools.``` It's wrong. I've commited to app store using osx 10.10

Comment: @Gank you have submitted your app succesfully to appstore from os x yosemite ?

Comment: @erhnby Yes. https://itunes.apple.com/app/rubiks-2048-2048-3d-version/id881944742?ls=1&mt=8  Just don't use XCode 6 to commit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the libcurl framework that I originally downloaded from Apple some years ago. I tried to manually change the files in the framework to remove the symbolic links, and got it to compile and run ok, but it failed the App Store validation process. In the end I removed the framework totally and switched to using "-lcurl" instead.